# socket problem in Android

Tags: c, android-ndk

H!

I have source in C, which is use the
`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` C method.
I use the NDK and make the jni. Everything is fine, but the application don't work correctly;
The original C method return 5 in the console. In Android that value is -1.

I try to add the C source file the #include < socket.h>, but this is not the solution.
Something to add AndroidManifest.xml or the Android.mk?

Thanks

Comment: How about posting some actual code?

Comment: the code is open source: msrplib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the NDK so I don't know if this is the same, but for a regular Android project you need to specify the "INTERNET" permission in the manifest, in order to use the sockets.

Comment: The permission is enforced through Linux process capabilities, so it works the same whether you're in native or interpreted code.